# Sampling uniformly from many circles on the sphere efficiently in matlab

Tags: matlab, rotation, statistics, transformation

I have a 3-by-N matrix `X` whose columns are vectors on the unit sphere (i.e., the Euclidean length of each vector is `1`), and I have a 1-by-N vector `Theta` whose entries are all angles between `0` and `pi`. For each `i`, there is a circle on the sphere centered at `X(:,i)` defined as the set of all points that have the angle `Theta(i)` with `X(:,i)`. I would like to get one uniform sample from the circle for each `i`, avoiding `for` loops because they can be slow in Matlab. I know that in vectorized Matlab code I can easily get one sample each from all circles with angles in `Theta` if I assume the center of all circles is `[0,0,1]`, and then I know how to get a rotation matrix (using [Rodrigues rotation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula)) that rotates `[0,0,1]` to another desired vector `x`, so for each `i`, I can just apply this rotation matrix to the sample point I obtained assuming `[0,0,1]` was the center.

I would like to this for all `i` without for loops, i.e. using array/matrix/vector notation.

Comment: I edited your question a bit, but it would be good to simplify it. There's no need to go into tedious detail. If anything provide a code snippet of how you do this for N = 1 so it's clear what your asking.

Comment: ok, now shorter -- it can't get any shorter without giving the hint that Rodrigues rotation might be key, which evidently is provoking some useful response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using [Rodrigues' rotation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula), you're trying to convert from [axis-angle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis-angle) representation to [rotation matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix). You're in luck. I happen to have written fast vectorized code to do exactly what I believe you're asking about. You can can find the code here: [`axang2rotmat.m`](http://biorobots.cwru.edu/personnel/adh/stackoverflow/02/axang2rotmat.m). Use is pretty straightforward (read the help):

```
n = 1e3;                % Number of axis-angles and rotation matrices
th = pi*rand(1,n);      % Random rotation angles between 0 and pi
v  = normc(rand(3,n));  % Random rotation vectors, normalized across columns
R = axang2rotmat(v,th); % Generate n rotation matrices, R is 3-by-3-n
```

Note, the above code is just to demonstrate the use of `axang2rotmat` and *won't give you uniformly sampled rotation matrices* (See [Miles, Biometrika 1962](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2333716) for details on why and workaround). I recommend that you calculate random rotation matrices directly, however. You can us another of my functions for that: [`randrotmat.m`](http://biorobots.cwru.edu/personnel/adh/stackoverflow/02/randrotmat.m).

I also have code to convert back from rotation matrices to axis-angle and check if a particular matrix is a rotation matrix [here](http://biorobots.cwru.edu/personnel/adh/stackoverflow/02/).

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this gets me almost all the way there; I will have to compute the `v` and `th` matrices but that won't be hard.  The only remaining detail is how to apply each 3x3 matrix in the 3x3xn array to each corresponding column vector in my 3xn matrix.  Is there an easy way to do this avoiding for loops?  Or will I have to mex?

Comment: @user2566092: First, see my edit about uniform sampling. The code above is just provided to show how to use `axang2rotmat` for conversion. It does not perform the uniform sampling. But I'm not sure that you even need to start with an axis-angle representation and so could just use `randrotmat`. Second, don't be afraid of `for` loops. Used judiciously and in the right places, they can be plenty fast in newer version of Matlab.

Comment: I will have my own special `v` and `th` (not random) and your code will nicely give the corresponding rotation matrices, and I will also have my own 3xn matrix of 3-d points, where I want to apply rotation matrix `i` to vector `i` in my matrix.  I'm not sure if/how to do this last step with a matlab one-liner?

Comment: Why do you need to do it in one line? I don't know of a way offhand (seems like this would be a separate StackOverflow question anyways). And a one-line solution is not necessarily faster than [a `for` loop with proper pre-allocation of memory](http://www.matlabtips.com/matlab-is-no-longer-slow-at-for-loops/). And [don't prematurely optimize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).

Comment: ok thanks, I'll try and see if a matlab for loop runs fast enough, and if not, then at least the required mex will be much easier now that you've given me a way to quickly get all my rotation matrices.